# vb.net Datagridview scrollbar won't show last column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, scroll

I'm working with Visual studio 2012 - Visual Basic.net

In my DGV I set the .AutoSizeMode for each column as follows:

```
with dgv_Clients
.Columns("Name").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
.Columns("Phone").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
.Columns("Email").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
.Columns("Address").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
end with
```

This configuration makes all cells to show the full text inside and the last column will be as big as needed to fit the blank space.

The problem comes when I resize the form shorter than the 3 columns; the horizontal scroll bar is shown but it doesn't show the last column.

If I change the "AutoSizeMode" from "Fill" to "AllCells" the scroll bar works fine but if the form is resized too long there is an ugly blank space.

Question:

How can I make the scroll bar to show the last column when the "AutoSizeMode" is set to "Fill" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a minimum width of the fill column like this:

```
.Columns("Address").MinimumWidth = 100
```

The default value of this property is `5`.